# Connecting two components in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I would like to build something that allows the connection of two components, kind of like a guitar cable will plug into an amp from a guitar.  So I want to connect to one point, and then drag the connection to a second point and have there be some natural hang in the rope.  I made this example from a previous SO question ([Three.js rope / cable effect - animating thick lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416963/three-js-rope-cable-effect-animating-thick-lines)), but I can't seem to get the calculation right.  So the question would be, how would I be able to make a function with this signature:

```
function drawSpline(startPoint, endPoint, ropeLength) {
    // returns a new THREE.Line object with a natural curvature for "slack" in the rope between the two points
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
scene.add(camera);
camera.position.z = 10;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();


const RADIUS = 1;
const SEGMENTS = 16;
const RINGS = 16;

const sphereMaterial =
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
    {
      color: 0xCC0000
    });

const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(
    RADIUS,
    SEGMENTS,
    RINGS),
  sphereMaterial);

sphere.position.z = 0;
const pointLight =
  new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);

// set its position
pointLight.position.x = 10;
pointLight.position.y = 50;
pointLight.position.z = 130;

// add to the scene
scene.add(pointLight);

const shiftRatio = 7.5;

scene.add(drawSpline({x: 0, y: -3, z: 0}, {x: 6, y: 1, z: 0}, 'blue'));



function drawSpline(beginning, end, clr){
    let ySign = Math.sign((end.y + beginning.y) / 2)
    let appliedRatio = shiftRatio;
    let midVector = new THREE.Vector3( (end.x + beginning.x) / 8, (end.y+beginning.y)/2, (end.z+beginning.z)/ 2 )
    let positionVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,end.y-beginning.y,end.z-beginning.z)
    let orthogVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,positionVector.z,-positionVector.y).normalize() 


    var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
        new THREE.Vector3( beginning.x, beginning.y, beginning.z ),
        midVector.clone().addScaledVector(orthogVector,ySign*appliedRatio),
        new THREE.Vector3( end.x, end.y, end.z ),
    ]);

    var points = curve.getPoints( 20 );
  console.log(points);
    var geometry = (new THREE.BufferGeometry()).setFromPoints( points );
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : clr } );

    // Create the final object to add to the scene
    var curveObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    return curveObject;
}
```

Comment: http://www.physics.smu.edu/fattarus/catenary.html

I believe this is the answer I'm looking for

Comment: You could probably copy this demo for 3D splines https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_spline_editor

Comment: not bad but a little bit off